# Performing POST on a URL string in Django

Tags: python, django, post, linkedin-api

I'm using the LinkedIn Authentication at: http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication and I need to make a post. I'm familiar with making a GET request for example as:

```
client = oauth.Client(consumer, access_token)
resp,content = client.request("http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?format=json", "GET", "")
```

Which used Oauth authentication. However for the Post part of the authentication, I have to POST an example string such as:

```
https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken?grant_type=authorization_code
                                           &code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE
                                           &redirect_uri=YOUR_REDIRECT_URI
                                           &client_id=YOUR_API_KEY
                                           &client_secret=YOUR_SECRET_KEY
```

and my simple question relates to understanding what the best way to do this is - without using the Oauth (assuming that is the correct approach), since I have returned the AUTHORIZATION_CODE. Apologies if this is a simple question.

So in other words, I have a string of the above form, now, How do I perform a post?

I've tried using cURL. But I find the code fails at the post line: `c.perform()`. Here is the code I am using:

```
   accesscode = request.GET.get('code')
    redirect_uri = 'http://www.example.com'
    url_post = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken'
    postdata = urllib2.quote('grant_type=authorization_code&code='+accesscode+'&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri+'&client_id='+consumer_key+'&client_secret='+consumer_secret)
    #return HttpResponse(postdata)

    c = pycurl.Curl()
    c.setopt(c.URL, url_post)
    c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postdata)
    c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)
    c.setopt(c.FAILONERROR, True)
    c.perform()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error at /loginsuccess/
(22, 'The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request')
```

Here is the code for how I am obtaining the first stage of the Authentication (as is suggested by the LI documentation):

```
def login(request):
    redirect_uri       =   urllib2.quote('http://127.0.0.1:8080/loginsuccess')
    codeURL = "https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id=c3skrqz5wqmm&scope=r_fullprofile&state=DCEEFWF45453sdffef425&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri
    return HttpResponseRedirect(codeURL)
```

Here is the latest traceback that I am getting after using the code suggested below to post the data. I have a number of questions that I will outline after the trace.

Error:

HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8888): Max retries exceeded with url: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken (Caused by : [Errno 111] Connection refused)

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:9000/loginsuccess/?code=AQQKMnhjMNKFEu08DkftejkNLQgSz-mIsMZtE36rGxrLfycx331iLXeC3LdAq63OTQeATAEXrA7FxgHSJWVHyh_iWyIEzVR6jp4zJsz41tpRipS14RE&state=DCEEFWF45453sdffef425

Django Version: 1.4.5
Python Version: 2.7.4
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles')
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/brett/LinkedIn/brett/brett/views.py" in loginsuccess
  68.   r = requests.post(access_token_url, data=postdata)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py" in post
  88.     return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py" in request
  44.     return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py" in request
  335.         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py" in send
  438.         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py" in send
  327.             raise ConnectionError(e)

Exception Type: ConnectionError at /loginsuccess/
Exception Value: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8888): Max retries exceeded with url: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
```

Plus with the request information there is still no POST data it would seem:

Request information

GET
Variable    Value
state
u'XX'
code
u'XX'
POST
No POST data
FILES
No FILES data

Here is more details.

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:9000/loginsuccess/?code=XXX&state=XXX
Django Version: 1.4.5
Exception Type: ConnectionError
Exception Value:    
HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=8888): Max retries exceeded with url: https://api.linkedin.com/uas/oauth/accessToken (Caused by <class 'socket.error'>: [Errno 111] Connection refused)
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send, line 327
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
```

---

```
Fiddler results:

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
P3P: CP="CAO DSP COR CUR ADMi DEVi TAIi PSAi PSDi IVAi IVDi CONi OUR DELi SAMi UNRi PUBi OTRi IND PHY ONL UNI PUR FIN COM NAV INT DEM CNT POL PRE"
X-LI-UUID: dI14TYAfd/RHJ8mVmAN8Gg==
Location: http://127.0.0.1:9000/loginsuccess?code=XX=XX
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Date: Thu, 05 Sep 2013 19:26:48 GMT
X-Li-Fabric: PROD-ELA4
Set-Cookie: _lipt=deleteMe; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: leo_auth_token="XX"; Version=1; Max-Age=1799; Expires=Thu, 05-Sep-2013 19:56:47 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sl="delete me"; Version=1; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: sl="delete me"; Version=1; Domain=.www.linkedin.com; Max-Age=0; Expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:10 GMT; Path=/
Set-Cookie: lang="v=2&lang=en-us"; Version=1; Domain=linkedin.com; Path=/
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
Age: 1
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
X-Li-Pop: PROD-IDB2

14
�����������������
0
```

Comment: Did you try changing the second parameter to `POST` and passing your data in the third?

Comment: I'm hazy as to whether Oauth is required for this operation by LinkedIn so trying to avoid using client as this is instantiated in another method.

Comment: You can always use curl.

Comment: Curl? Is that python?

Comment: I tried using the following answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2863260/posting-a-form-using-python-and-curl To make a POST but I get a GET error!

Comment: I've tried using cURL. But I find the code fails at the post line: c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postdata). Here is the code I am using: `accesscode = request.GET.get('code')
redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080/success'
url_post = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken'
postdata ='grant_type=authorization_code&code='+accesscode+'&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri+'&client_id='+consumer_key+'&client_secret='+consumer_secret
 postdata = 'xyz=fred'
 c = pycurl.Curl()
 c.setopt(c.URL, url_post)
 c.setopt(c.POSTFIELDS, postdata)
 c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)
 c.setopt(c.FAILONERROR, True)
 c.perform()`

Comment: So what's the error? And you redirect uri is wrong. Should not be localhost.

Comment: I've updated things, but still cannot get the post functioning correctly. Note I have now encoded the post data as it contained a URL - whether this is the right thing to do or not, I do not know.

Comment: Have you considered using a library? http://django-social-auth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/backends/linkedin.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Take a look at [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) (install with `pip install requests`), you can make the POST request easily with just some lines of code:

```
import requests

accesscode = request.GET.get('code')
redirect_uri = 'http://www.example.com'
url = 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/accessToken'
# ... your code ...

postdata = {
    'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
    'code': accesscode,
    'redirect_uri': redirect_uri,
    'client_id': consumer_key,
    'client_secret': consumer_secret,
}

r = requests.post(url, data=postdata)
print(r.status_code)
print(r.text)
```

You can try this in Python shell since I think it's simple enough to do so.

Comment: Eventually this will go on Google App Engine. Do you know if this is supported? It appears on the surface to be, but not as yet fully delved.

Comment: It had some problems before but is supported now, check https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/498

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying now, but I wonder if this is now an issue with LinkedIn. I'm posting, but getting a 400 error. However all the data seems to be being passed just fine.

Comment: Is there any easy way to debug this?

Comment: And btw could you post the previous step when you get the authorization code also? Perhaps you got the wrong code?

Comment: I have included the first part too.

Comment: Hmm you got the correct authorization code from LinkedIn and the above code should work flawlessly, I can't see any problem here. Probably this is LinkedIn's issue. Can you do `print postdata` above to debug and also post the full traceback if there is an error?

Comment: I'VE kicked this over to LinkedIn. I do not understand why after getting auth code and immediately requesting access token this fails as it does!

Comment: Use the program Fiddler2 to observe the requests as they go back and forth.

Comment: I'm playing with Fiddler2 but still not getting much joy. The latest traceback is the following: